# How to set y axis labels if it appears as [1,2.12,1.2,5 ] , they should be [1.00,2.12,1.20,5.00]

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to have the number of decimal places fixed consistently throughout the y-axis tick values?

Comment: E.g. if my y-axis tick values were [0, 1.5, 3, 4.5, 6, 7.5], they would change to [0.0, 1.5, 3.0, 4.5, 6.0, 7.5], or if they were [1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2] they would change to [1.00, 1.25, 1.50, 1.75, 2.00].

Answer (score 2):

yes it is possible, just use the `format` option under `labels`:

```
yAxis: {
    labels:{format:'{value:.2f}'}
},
```

Adjust the number before the `f` to set the elements' number you would like to have after the comma.
Check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mushigh/Lwrb69rj/) exanmple:

```
$(function () {
 $('#container').highcharts({

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            labels:{format:'{value:.2f}'}
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }]
    });
});
```